# Как подписаться под письмом, если оба автора имеют одинаковые отчества?

Tags: ономастика, оформление-текста

Если письмо пишут два человека с одинаковым отчеством, то как они должны закончить письмо?
Иван и Мария — Васильевны или Васильевичи?

Answer (score 2):

В начале письма (при обращении) и в его конце (при подписи) отчества не "объединяются".
Такое вполне возможно только с фамилиями (скажем, супругов).

*А вам, Александр **Петрович**, Андрей Георгиевич, Юнна **Петровна** и Евгений Александрович, спасибо за подсказку.*
В. Соловьев. Не только Евтушенко

*21. Максимовы Елена Николаевна и Сергей Николаевич*
Из списка многодетных семей...

*Дорогие мои люди, Екатерина **Ивановна** и Михаил **Иванович**, вы неправы...*

Концовка письма может выглядеть так:
Искренне Ваши,
Иван Васильевич и Мария Васильевна (Петровы).

Отступление
В семьях, в компаниях и сообществах, где поддерживаются дружеские, особенные отношения, такие словечки-отчества вполне приемлемы.
В нашей семье есть два брата — Бо́рьевичи; мы с сестрой тоже имеем "множественное" отчество, "нестандартное" — для друзей и близких. "Свои", конечно, сразу понимают — о ком разговор или кто подписал поздравительную открытку.
Тут надо ещё учитывать, что в Эстонии в паспортах отчества отсутствуют.

Answer (score 1):

В неофициальном, народно-разговорном стиле возможно использование мужского варианта отчества для нескольких лиц разного пола: "Иван да Марья Васильевичи".

Но это в какой-то степени допустимо только в устной речи или в шутливом письме, в тексте. **Подписывать** так даже ироническое письмо я бы не стал. В серьезном тексте - абсолютно исключено.

Остальное - см. Римма Михайлова.